# Time problem with this code 

Tags: java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class test {

    /*
     * Calculate the difference between two date/times   * 
     * 
     */

    private static long dateDiff(Date toDate, Date fromDate) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(toDate);
        long ms = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.setTime(fromDate);
        ms -= cal.getTimeInMillis();
        return ms;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try {
            d1 = sdf.parse("11:00:00");
            d2 = sdf.parse("10:00:00");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long result = dateDiff(d1, d2);

        Date time = new Date(result);

        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

When I run it I get this result :

Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 CET 1970

I would expect 1 hour difference ?! again a problem with Timezone??

Any idea how I can fix it.

thx all

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you are going to do extensive work with dates and time you should use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It is far superior to the JDK API (and more friendly IMO).

Comment: Your calculation is correct -- it is a timezone issue.  Put a print statement in the method and just directly convert the milliseconds to another unit (e.g., minutes) and print it out.

Comment: I need the time difference between two Date fields and then put it in MySql (time format)

Comment: @Paul W - actually, the real issue is that you can't treat a duration as a date and expect it to work.

Comment: @Stephen C - I know it isn't how the Date api is designed to be used, but if you know that your difference will be less than 24 hours, you can put it into a Date and format it using just the time elements as above to fake it.  Of course, you have to work out timezone issues...

Comment: @Paul W - and you think that's a good idea?  You think it is what the OP should implement this?  I don't ... and I don't believe it is a good idea to send the OP off on a wild goose chase by telling him "it is a timezone issue" ... when he shouldn't be doing it that way in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you expect this to do, but what you are actually doing is outputting the date corresponding to one hour after midnight on Jan 1 1970, using the default timezone.

You seem to want to Date to represent a duration (i.e. a number of seconds).  It doesn't do that, and neither will the Date formatters render a Date as a duration.

---

> I need the time difference between two Date fields and then put it in MySql (time format)

<strike>For what you are trying to do, you need calculate the duration value as a `long`, then use the `java.sql.Time(long)` constructor to create a [`Time`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) object.  You can either serialize this object using its `toString()` method or use it as a parameter in a JDBC prepared statement.</strike>

It turns out that my advice above is incorrect too.

Your real problem is that the SQL Time type is for representing times ... not durations.  In fact, SQL does not have a dedicated duration type, so the best you can do is represent the duration as an integer number of seconds or milliseconds or whatever.

---

(For the more general case, the Joda Time libraries are generally thought to provide the best APIs for manipulating dates, times and related temporal values.  But for this simple case, the standard J2SE libraries should suffice ... provided that you use them correctly.)

Comment: I need the time difference between two Date fields and then put it in MySql (time format)

Comment: I used something like this :                                                           Date sessionDate = session.getSessionTime();
   long sessionDateInMillis = sessionDate.getTime();
   java.sql.Date sqlSessionDate = new java.sql.Date(sessionDateInMillis);

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a difference of two Date types can not be represented by another Date type.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just take the milliseconds of both dates and substract them from each other?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d1);
long d1ms = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.setTime(d2);
long d2ms = cal.getTimeInMillis();

long diffMs = d1ms - d2ms;
long diffHour = diffMs * 1000 * 60 * 60;
```

Comment: I need the time difference between the two Date fields and then put it in MySql (time format). so I  thought to start from a Date Format to get to Time (MySql easily).  Normally the difference will be minutes

Comment: The time difference is not expressable in the MySQL TIME format. "60 minutes" is not a valid Date.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this setting timezone to GMT. Remove day, month in words in the resultant time difference. This method does nothing but assumes these many milliseconds since starting of time counter in java, which is 1st Jan 1970. So if your result says 3rd Jan 1970 means 3 days have passed since time counter started, which is perfect. You just need to interpret it properly, but formatting your answer

```
...
long result = dateDiff(d1, d2); //This is your code in main([])
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss SSS");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(result )));
```

Comment: Ughhh ... did you read the OP's comments where he explained what he is really trying to do?

Comment: Date is the most irritating things in databases, so this is the issue :). But since you should not be bothered with how date is stored in a particular database, like as milliseconds since 1st jan 1970 or as data time string in some standard format. The trick is to read it back properly and set timezone to GMT and read the values. You do not need any of the time APIs if your duration is short, just use  `diffMs * 1000 * 60 * 60` or some modulus operations only in case the date difference spans more than a month some tricky date calculations comes in, use date APIs then.

Comment: Durations and dates are conceptually different things.  His problem is that he is trying to format and store a duration as a date / time value.  This is broken.